# How can i count the collisions in this hash function?

Tags: c++, hash, prefix, hash-collision

This is a prefix hashing function. i want to count the number of collisions in this method but i am not sure how to do it. It seems like it might be simple but i just cant think of a great way to do it....

```
int HashTable_qp::preHash(string & key, int tableSize )
{
    string pad = "AA";
    //some words in the input are less than 3 letters
    //I choose to pad the string with A because all padded characters 
    //have same ascii val, which is low, and will hopefully alter the results less
    if (key.length() < 3)
    {
        key.append(pad);
    }
    return ( key[0] + 27 * key[1] + 729 * key[2] ) % tableSize;
}
```

Comment: create a histogram unsigned [tablesize], generate some (all) the possible strings and compute their hashval, and update the histogram accordingly histogram[hashval] +=1;

Comment: @wildplasser, that would be the easiest way.  My answer would be faster.  If it's not performance critical I'd go with **wild's** idea.  (You should probably post that as an answer, to help others find it when they find this page.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array as the underlying data structure do:
`int hash = preHash(&key, array.length);
 if(array[hash] != null)
    this.count++;`

If it's an array of linked lists do:

```
if(array[hash] != null && *(array[hash]) != null)
this.count++
```

If you only have access to the stl library I believe just testing that element is null
before adding it would be enough after calling the hash function.

Comment: i am using stl's, can you show me how it would look taking stl's into consideration.

Comment: Easiest way is to inherit it and override it call: HashTable_qt::PreHash in the derived class, but instantiate the derived class and assign it a value and give the derived class a field variable called CollisionCount and before you add a new value initialize it to 0 and after call it and it should have the new value if greater than 1 the function was called with a new key

Comment: int Prehash(string & key, int tableSize )
{
    HashMap_qt::Prehash(key, tablesize);
    CollisionCount++;
}

in main
HashTable_qt2* map = new HashMap_qt2()
map.CollisionCount = 0;
map.Add(...);
cout << map.CollisionCount;

Answer (score 1):

create a histogram:

```
 unsigned histogram[tablesize] = {0};
```

generate some (all) possible strings and compute their hashval, and update the histogram accordingly:

```
for(iter=0; iter < somevalue; iter++) {
 hashval = hashfunc( string.iterate(iter) ); // I don't know c++
 histogram[hashval] +=1;
 }
```

Now you have to analyze the hashtable for lumps / clusters. Rule of thumb is that for `(tablesize==iter)`, you expect about 30 % cells with count =1, and about 30 % empty; the rest has two or more.

If you sum all the `(count*(count+1))/2`, and divide by the tablesize, you should expect around 1.5. A bad hashfunction gives higher values, a perfect hash would only have cells with count=1 (and thus: ratio=1) With linear probing you should of course never use tablesize=niter, but make tablesize bigger, say twice as big. You can use the same metric (number of probes / number of entries), to analyse its performance, though.

UPDATE: a great introduction on hashfunctions and their performance can be found at http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions .

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of integers, each representing one hash.  When you're done making the hashes loop back through the array in a nested loop.  If you had the following array,

```
[0] -> 13
[1] -> 5
[2] -> 12
[3] -> 7
[4] -> 5
```

For each item **i** in **0..n**, check items **i+1..n** for matches.  In English that would be: check if each element equals any of the elements *after* it.